# ASP.NET MVC 3 HiddenFor Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, hidden-field

I have two hidden input fields in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="long" id="long" value="" />
```

I am assigning their value by doing the following:

```
document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
document.getElementById('long').value = lng;
```

Can someone please tell me how I can remove the hidden `<input>` fields and replace them with a `@Html.HiddenFor<>` and make my Javascript update the HiddenFor? I want to do this because it will obviously automatically bind the data.

My HiddenFor currently looks something like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Listing.Location.Latitude);
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Listing.Location.Longitude);
```

I change the Javascript to do this:

```
document.getElementById('Listing.Location.Latitude').value = lat;
document.getElementById('Listing.Location.Longitude').value = lng;
```

I get the following error in the Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

Can anyone see where I am going horribly wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Ids of these fields will have underscores not dots, their names will have the dots.  Try this:

```
document.getElementById('Listing_Location_Latitude').value = lat;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Listing.Location.Latitude, new {id = "theIdyouWant"})
```

So you can get the element using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("theIdyouWant")
```

Comment: Ah. Didn't know I could specify an id like that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `id` will be another. `Listing.Location.Latitude` is name attribute.

For example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.General.Site_Name)
```

generated as:

```
<input id="General_Site_Name" type="text" name="General.Site_Name" />
```